# Поиск максимального числа в массиве

Tags: массивы, c++

Здравствуйте, пишу фукнцию для поиска самого большого числа в массиве

Алгоритм:

> 1. Объявить большим 1 число.
> 2. Перейти к следующему числу
> 3. Если оно больше объявленного, то заменить объявленное большее на него.
> 4. Если номер числа меньше 10, то перейти к п.2
> 5. Вывести найденное большее.
> 6. Конец

Сама функция:

```
int FindMax(int* mass,int count) 
{
    int max=null;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (i = 0)
        {
            max = mass[i];
            continue;
        }
        if (mass[i] > max)
        {
            max = mass[i];
        }
        if (i < count)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Ошибок нет, но сложилось впечатление что цикл просто тупо бесконечный хотя переменная count=8

Comment: На C++ вне учебного кода следует [использовать](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

    std::max_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v))

(а вместо пары из указателя на первый элемент и количества элементов использовать стандартные контейнеры).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Много лишнего кода из-за которого теряется прозрачность алгоритма, а также могут быть ошибки при непредусмотренных входных параметрах.

сделай так:

```
int FindMax(int* mass,int count) 
{
    if(count <  1) return null;

    int max = mass[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
        if (mass[i] > max)
            max = mass[i];

    return max;
}
```

Comment: return null;

а потом будете делать проверку в стиле ?

    int m = FindMax(......,..);
    if (m == null) {
      std::cout << "максимум не найден!";
    }

Comment: `return null` — это кромешный ад.

Comment: а если ещё максимальный элемент будет равен 0...

Comment: минус за return null

Comment: предложите свой "правильный" вариант в случае, если кол-во элементов в массиве равно нулю. я считаю, что это вполне нормальный способ сообщить о том, что максимум не найден наверх.

Comment: дело в том, что в с/с++ null в 99% случаев и есть ноль. Поэтому принимающая сторона не сможет отличить 0 от null, как бы она не старалась.

Вот такой "примерчик" (выведет `null == 0   -> 1`, то есть истина):

    #include <iostream>
    
    int retNull()
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    
    int main ()
    {
      std::cout << "null == 0   -> " << (retNull() == 0) << std::endl;
      return 0;
    }

да, кстати, в С++ нет `null`. Там есть `NULL`. В новом стандарте есть `nullptr`.

Comment: @MuFF, ну, если Вы сторонник проверки всего и вся и в функции и в коде ее вызывающем, то стоит просто чуть изменить прототип функции. 

Пусть она возвращает указатель на максимальный элемент.

Получим что-то вроде

    int *
    find_max (int *arr, size_t cnt)
    {
       int *max = 0; // NULL тоже подойдет
       if (cnt) {
          max = arr;
          for (int *p = arr + 1; p < arr + cnt; p++)
             if (*p > *max)
                max = p;
       }
       return max;
    }

И вызываем как-то так
  
    if (!(pmax = find_max(arr, 3)))
      puts("Impossible!");

Comment: @avp, ну вот с возвращением указателя гораздо лучше. ) то, что null == 0 -> true, так этого требует стандарт языка. это исключительная ситуация, которой нельзя аргументировать. поэтому лучше null использовать, 0 - это нулевое значение, а у нас значение отсутствует.

Comment: @MuFF, Вы **серьезно** считаете, что в реальном сегодняшнем харде возможно отличие 0 от null (т.е. предопределенного несуществующего адреса)?

Смотрите на жизнь конкретней, Си предназначен для тесной связи с аппаратурой (и кресты никуда от этого не денутся,  как бы ни хотели этого все профессора).

Answer (score 10):

Типичнейшая ошибка начинающего изучать C. Проблема в строчке

```
if (i = 0)
```

Одинарное = в C - это присваивание. Сравнение выполняется двойным равно ==. На каждой итерации цикла вы присваиваете счётчику значение 0, поэтому условие `i < count` выполняется всегда.

И ещё. Отдельная проверка `if (i < count)` здесь не нужна, её выполняет цикл.

Comment: Вот поэтому я приручил себя всегда компилировать с опциями "-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror".

Answer (score 6):

Странный код, много лишнего. К примеру,

```
 if (i < count)
 {
     continue;
 }
```

не нужно, так как это тавтология (цикл и так нужно повторять, пока `i < count`).

```
 int max=null;
```

Вы случайно не с Java перешли на плюсы? В плюсах эта строка выглядит дико (хотя обычно и компилируется).

исправим все

```
int FindMax(int* mass,int count) 
{
    if (count < 1)
      return 0; // защита от непредвиденных случаев.
    int max=mass[0]; // нулевой элемент будет.

    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) // начинаем с 1, так как нулевой уже приняли за max
    {
        if (mass[i] > max)
        {
            max = mass[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Но это не сильно плюсовый код... это так, си. Хотите плюсовый код - используйте `std::vector` и [max_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/).

Comment: не, я перешёл с пхп

Answer (score 4):

Ваша ошибка тут:

```
if (i = 0)
```

Должно быть:

```
if (i == 0)
```

Для устранения подобных ляпов советуют писать проверку на равенство в обратном порядке:

```
if (0 == i)
```

Вообще ваш код весьма странен. Много лишних телодвижений

Answer (score 0):

Сначала надо проверить переменную count. А нужно есть ли хотя бы один элементов в массиве, в котором мы будем что-то искать. Если элементов нет, то сразу завершаем выполнение функции.

1. Объявить большим 1 число - мне кажется лучше переменной `max` присвоить значение первого элементам массива. Ведь мы уже точно знаем, что хотя бы один элемент в массиве у нас есть.

Остальное в алгоритме верно.